# No consigo devolver el nombre

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando que un método de una clase me devuelva un string que se ha introducido a través de teclado mostrándola en un cout. Sin embargo algo estoy haciendo mal ya que aunque el programa compila no consigo que me muestre el string introducido. Aún así mi IDE me da el siguiente aviso:

> Assign return value to new variable

Supongo que será una tontería  pero llevo un buen rato estancado y no se me ocurre nada. He aquí el código.

**Player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <string>

class Player{
public:
  Player(std::string name, int health, int damage);

      void setName(std::string name);
      std::string getName() const;

      void setHealth(int health);
      int getHealth() const;

      void setDamage(int damage);
      int getDamage() const;
  private:
   std::string name;
   int health;
   int damage;
 };  
  #endif /* JUGADOR_H */
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(std::string name, int health, int damage){
setName("default");
setHealth(100);
setDamage(30);
 }

void Player::setName(std::string name)
{
name = name;
}

void Player::setHealth(int health){

health = 100;
}

void Player::setDamage(int damage){

damage = 30;
}

std::string Player::getName() const{

return name;

}

int Player::getHealth() const{

return health;
}

int Player::getDamage() const{

return damage;

}
```

Tengo problemas para poder insertar el código completo, así que por aquí os dejo el github donde lo tengo subido para que se vea mejor:

[Player.cpp](https://github.com/Jackieto/Text-Dragons/blob/master/Player.cpp)

[main.cpp](https://github.com/Jackieto/Text-Dragons/blob/master/main.cpp)

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
std::string name;
std::cout <<"Hello! Write your name "<<std::endl;
getline(std::cin, name);
Player player(name, 100, 30);
std::cout <<"Welcome "<<player.getName();
}
```

Comment: "*Estoy intentando que un método de una clase me devuelva un string *". Las clases no devuelven nada, son las funciones. ¿En qué función de qué clase está tu problema? Señala la parte del código relevante a tu pregunta, ayúdanos a ayudarte.

Comment: Básicamente en el main.cpp en el cout estoy intentando que muestre un string que guardé en una variable a través de un getline. Esta variable se la pasé a la clase para que esta la devolviera con getName(). Al menos así es como he entendido que debería hacerlo, aunque probablemente me equivoque. Supongo que si echas un vistazo al main.cpp verás de lo que estoy hablando.

Al compilar el programa muestra "Bienvenido  !" ignorando el getName()

Comment: ¿El problema está en `main`? ¿Podemos ver tu `main`?

Comment: Hay un link en el post original, lo vuelvo a poner:

https://github.com/Jackieto/Text-Dragons/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: En el lugar en que me encuentro no tengo permisos para acceder a los links que has compartido; si algo es relevante para tu pregunta debería estar en la pregunta no en una fuente externa.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya está incluido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas haciendo una autoasignación:

```
void Player::setName(std::string name)
{
    name = name;
}
```

Cambia el nombre del parámetro:

```
void Player::setName(std::string otro_name)
{
    name = otro_name;
}
```

O desambigua con `this`:

```
void Player::setName(std::string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}
```